# CakePHP undefinded index on table that exists

Tags: php, cakephp

When i was posting my cakephp project online a view wasn't working for 100% anymore.
Local the view shows correct data but online it shows only on one of the 21 values

```
undefined index: commission_total [APP/View/Brokeraccountupdates/detail.ctp, line 77]
```

There where no typo's and the database field does exist.
i made a phpinfo on-line to compare the settings of php and mysql versions.

the code is identical and the server settings are good.
(paginator is good to).
can someone help me?

Comment: It's hard to help when there's nothing to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting server has problems with permissions ect we use a new hosting server and the problem disappears. 
thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Ive had this issue before normally it is caused by the model being cached. Try deleting the model cache for your app:

```
cd <cake_app_root>
rm -rf app/tmp/cache/model/*
```

Or navigate to the directory in an FTP client and remove the files, however you manage your server

Comment: In that case show the code for the part that is failing. Also check that the database config is pointing to the correct database, that the fields are created in the database and that they are populated.

Comment: We can not share the code because the project is proprietary.

Comment: Then you would need to recreate the issue with non proprietary code and post that.

Comment: We can not share the code because the project is proprietary. most views show this field without any issues, it's just this one view that gives us trouble. we've also already checked it for typing errors ect.

Comment: Then you would need to recreate the issue with non proprietary code and post that. We cant debug code we cant see :(